# What should I use ? core Data or sqlite in iPhone SDKc

Tags: iphone, sqlite, core-data

I'm making dictionary, it have over 50000 rows. Now, I'm using sqlite for 30000 testing. It is slow for searching. I'm worrying about 50000 records. So, I'm thinking to use core data in iPhone SDK. Should I use coredata , instead of sqlite ? Which one is faster ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Core Data is built ontop of SQLite, what do you think? SQLite is the faster of the two.